# how to remove horizontal scroll bar of iframe at the bottom of a page html in google chrome?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have this problem in google chrome I checked firefox there is no scroll bar

HTML :

```
<iframe title="recaptcha challenge"  frameborder="0" scrolling="no"  
style="width: 400px; height: 580px;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
    // Options: visible, hidden, scroll, auto   
div.disabled {
    overflow-x: hidden; //horizontal
    overflow-y: scroll; //vertical
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work with the div cotaining the iframe in wordpress  I have this problem in the chrome browser

Comment: I am sorry. I don't know then.